Get records for same date from table in Oracle
I have a table where I want to get records where MODIFIED_DATE is same with count of 2
For example: If for job_id = 1234 there are 2 records with date MODIFIED_DATE = 04-10-2024 then it should filter that record.
Name                   Null?    Type           
---------------------- -------- -------------- 
JOB_PROGRESS_ID        NOT NULL NUMBER         
JOB_ID                          NUMBER         
STATUS_ID                       NUMBER         
HOTO_OFFERED_DATE               DATE           
HOTO_ACCEPTENCE_DATE            DATE           
LIT_ACCEPTENCE_DATE             DATE           
APPROVED_BY                     NVARCHAR2(200) 
APPROVED_DATE                   DATE           
REJECTED_BY                     NVARCHAR2(200) 
REJECTED_DATE                   DATE           
APPROV_REJECT_REMARK            NVARCHAR2(255)     
ABD_COMPLETED_LENGTH            NUMBER         
NE_SPAN_LENGTH                  NUMBER(10,4)   
CREATED_BY                      NVARCHAR2(200) 
CREATED_DATE           NOT NULL DATE           
MODIFIED_BY                     NVARCHAR2(200) 
MODIFIED_DATE                   DATE 


What's the question? Did you try writing a SQL query with a WHERE clause asking for a specific date? If it failed, it's probably because of the bad string . 04-10-24 isn't a date at all. It's a string in such an ambiguous format it's impossible to guess what it means. It's impossible to say if the year is 1904, 1924, 2004 or 2024. Any assumption you make is simply wrong. The date type is binary and has no format. If you call your query from a client using date-typed paramaters (actual parameters, not string interpolation), there won't be any ambiguity

@PanagiotisKanavos: I have updated the question for more information. I don't want data for particular date, I want it for all records

If you have to use a string, eg to specify a hard-coded date, use the unambiguous YYYY-MM-DD format. Check Oracle's DateTime Literal docs. Don't try to use anything other than YYYY-MM-DD though, and certainly not 2-digit years. Whatever you assume the current locale is, someone will run your code using a different one sooner or later and return bad results. That's how all those pensioner refused pension because he's an infant news come about

There's no new information in the question. No SQL query, no explanation of a problem. The string is still bad - Is that April 10th or October 4th ? The meaning will change depending on whether the caller uses a US locale or not. And guess what most developers use for convenience ....

What's the actual table schema (including the primary key) and what results do you want? Are you trying to find duplicate rows for the same JobID (not record)? One way would be to GROUP BY JobID, Modified and use HAVING COUNT(*)=2. Another is to use SELECT ..., COUNT() OVER (Partition by JobID, Modified) as JobsInDay in a CTE or subquery and then filter by JobsInDay. You could use ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION By JobId,Modified Order by ThePrimaryKey) instead of COUNT to find rows whose row number is >1

@PanagiotisKanavos: Its October 4th..

What is the question? Where are you stuck with the task? So far your request is something like "I want to do something. Please suggest." The only suggestion that comes to mind is "Do it." If this is not the answer you are looking for, describe the problem you are having.

@hud says who ? If you use AMERICAN_AMERICA it's April 10th. Don't use localized date strings. And edit the question to explain what you actually want, with sample data and desired output. I mentioned 3 different techniques to produce 3 different results and I can think of even more (self join on JobID & Modified where t1.ID!=T2.ID). Do you want to know the JobID of the duplicates (Group BY), the first or last duplicate row (Row_Number), all duplicate rows (Count OVER)?

If you want to find the job_id and modified_date when there are two rows in the table with those values then:
SELECT job_id, modified_date
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY job_id, modified_date
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (job_id, modified_by, modified_date) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice', DATE '2024-10-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Betty', DATE '2024-10-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Carol', DATE '2024-10-04' + INTERVAL '01:23:45' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Debra', DATE '2024-10-04' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Emily', DATE '2024-10-04' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



JOB_ID
MODIFIED_DATE




1
2024-10-04 00:00:00



If you want to list all the columns then:
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY job_id, modified_date)
           AS num_duplicates_per_job_per_day
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  num_duplicates_per_job_per_day = 2

Outputs:



JOB_ID
MODIFIED_BY
MODIFIED_DATE
NUM_DUPLICATES_PER_JOB_PER_DAY




1
Alice
2024-10-04 00:00:00
2


1
Betty
2024-10-04 00:00:00
2



Note: A DATE always has a date and time component so when you are comparing values then you are comparing with a precision of seconds (not days). If you are storing non-midnight time components and want to check for duplicates across an entire day then use TRUNC(modified_date) rather than modified_date in the queries.
SELECT job_id, TRUNC(modified_date)
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY job_id, TRUNC(modified_date)
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;

Outputs:



JOB_ID
TRUNC(MODIFIED_DATE)




2
2024-10-04 00:00:00


1
2024-10-04 00:00:00



and:
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY job_id, TRUNC(modified_date))
           AS num_duplicates_per_job_per_day
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  num_duplicates_per_job_per_day = 2;

Outputs:



JOB_ID
MODIFIED_BY
MODIFIED_DATE
NUM_DUPLICATES_PER_JOB_PER_DAY




1
Alice
2024-10-04 00:00:00
2


1
Betty
2024-10-04 00:00:00
2


2
Carol
2024-10-04 01:23:45
2


2
Debra
2024-10-04 23:59:59
2



fiddle

for some job_id I am getting more than 2 records also..how to handle that

@hud Use >= 2

i want only for count = 2, but with >= 2 i am getting more records of which count is > 0

@hud Edit your question and provide a [MRE] with the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; an English explanation (not code) of the logic that you want to implement; and the expected output for that sample data. Trying to debug something that we cannot see and when the logic is not thoroughly explained is difficult (impossible?) so help us to help you and provide all the information in the question.

It's unclear what the question wants - the only certain thing is that the localized date string will cause problems. It should be YYYY-MM-DD.
The question may be asking how to find all duplicate rows, one of the duplicate rows, or jobs with duplicates.
To find JobIDs with 2 or more rows in the same date, one can use GROUP BY with HAVING` :
Select JOB_ID, Modified_Date, Count(*)
FROM That_Table
GROUP BY JOB_ID, Modified_Date
Having Count(*)>1

To find all duplicates in a day, a CTE using COUNT() OVER can be used :
With multiples as 
(
    Select * ,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY JOB_ID, Modified_Date) as cnt
    FROM That_Table
)
select That_Table.* 
from multiples
where cnt=2

To find the extra row only, ROW_NUMBER can be used :
With multiples as 
(
    Select That_Table.* ,
        ROW_NUMBER(*) OVER (
            PARTITION BY JOB_ID, Modified_Date 
            Order BY JOB_PROGRESS_ID) as RN
    From That_Table
)
select multiples.* 
from multiples
where RN>1


Thanks. I wasn't trying to answer as much as prod the OP to actually explain what they want, given how many different ways the question can be interpreted or answered

"the only certain thing is that the localized date string will cause problems. It should be YYYY-MM-DD." No, it shouldn't. It should either be a date literal, a timestamp literal, a string explicitly converted using TO_DATE or a string that matches the NLS_DATE_FORMAT session parameter (but the latter is considered bad practice). The NLS_DATE_FORMAT could have the format DD-MM-YYYY or it could have the format YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS or many other formats but to say it must be a string in one specific format is incorrect.

@MT0 yes it should, because it's the only unambiguous format. Using localized formats is the cause of a lot of SO questions and real life problems like this Spanish family's. Using a localized format is just asking for trouble. As for Timestamp the question is about Date. And even then yes, the ISO8601 format should be used instead of localized ones

You may want it to be an unambiguous format but RRRR-MM-DD is only the default format if you are in Bulgaria, Sweden, Cambodia or (ignoring punctuation) Latvia or Lithuania (see Oracle's default DATE format). If the database is setup in any other territory then the default NLS_DATE_FORMAT will not match that and you will get an error.  fiddle A more unambiguous format would be YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS (since a DATE data-type in Oracle always has a time component).
